# How to correctly serve a static site on NGINX with node-restify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, next.js, restify

I'm having some issues with this, wondering if anyone had any insights.

I have a `public` controller

```
import restify from ‘restify’;

const { serveStatic } = restify.plugins;
const directory = __dirname + ‘/../../../public’;
const serveSite = () => serveStatic({ directory, default: ‘index.html’ });
const serveFile = file => serveStatic({ directory, file });

export default server => {
  server.get(‘/*’, serveSite());
  server.get(‘/about’, serveFile(‘about.html’));
};
```

My static site (which is built using `nextjs`) is built and stored in `/public` on the server, remotely. My NGINX location directive looks like this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Going to `/` and reloading serves the site correctly. Navigating to `/about` via the nav works fine, but if I refresh this route, I get a 404 page from NGINX. If I go to `/about.html` it works. Locally, just testing restify without NGINX involved, everything works fine so I feel it must be something to do with the server config.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the location directive needs an extra option

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

And everything works.